# connection terminated: Unexpected reception error FTP C #

Tags: c#

I'm using this code to download via FTP

```
 try
        {
            //const string url = ficFTP;
            string url = ficFTP;
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

            // Query size of the file to be downloaded
            WebRequest sizeRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);                
            sizeRequest.Credentials = credentials;
            sizeRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;                
            long size = (long)sizeRequest.GetResponse().ContentLength;                
            long sizeKb = size / 1024;

            progressBar1.Invoke(
                (MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(sizeKb)));

            // Download the file
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = credentials;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(dirLocal))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
                int read;
                while ((read = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    long position = (long)fileStream.Position;
                    long positionKb = position / 1024;
                    progressBar1.Invoke(
                        (MethodInvoker)(() => progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(positionKb)));
                }
            }
            lblDescarga.Text = "¡Descargado!";

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
```

I am downloading a file that weighs 4GB, the problem is that when the software has downloaded 3.22 GB it gives this error

> connection terminated: Unexpected reception

Could it be some open connection time problem to the server? is there any solution to this problem? I have been investigating but cannot find a solution.

I hope you can give me an idea. Thank you.

Comment: I this code being run from a Web Page/ Web Application ? Or Desktop /Console Application?

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual error message?  Your post is [the only result in a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22connection+terminated%3A+Unexpected+reception%22) for that message.

Comment: Hello, first of all, excuse me, I was wrong in labeling this is a Windows application .net is for desktop.

Comment: Yes, that is the error message it throws at me, it does not give me another type of message.

Answer (score 0):

All kinds of network connections are due to their nature unreliable and may fail at any time.

If the download fails consistently at exactly 3.22GB it suggest a software error rather than general unreliability. It can however be hard to tell if the problem is on the server or client. The client code looks reasonable as far as I can tell, so it might be a server problem.

One way to handle the problem would be to reconnect to the server and use [Seek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.seek?view=netframework-4.8) to jump to the place in the stream the failure occured and resume the copying. Not all streams support seeking however, so I do not know if this would work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

3.32 GB means, that client use 32bit operating or storage system (fat32). Try to copy big file other way to disc, just to be sure.